# What's the double curly braces '{{pricing_value}}' in phtml file?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, product-edit

I see the `'{{pricing_value}}'` in `/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/super/config.phtml`, I guess that it is a template engine expression, but not sure. What's it?

How does it get value? From the block `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Super_Config`?

If I want to process it's value, where should I go to edit? 
 `'{{pricing_value}}'` will show **null** when pricing_value set 0, but I want it just to show **0**. At the same time, when I leave it blank, it still blank.

Comment: It is js Template variables. check file Magento_ROOT/js/mage/adminhtml/product.js

Comment: @MineshPatel Up vote for your advise, but the product.js is large, where should I go to edit when pricing_value is 0 it should just to show 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do,
Open **product.js** file, go to line around `671`

Replace below code

```
if (!isNaN(pricingValue)) {
    templateVariables.set('pricing_value', pricingValue);
} else {
    templateVariables.unset('pricing_value');
}
```

with

```
if (!isNaN(pricingValue)) {
    templateVariables.set('pricing_value', pricingValue);
} else {
    templateVariables.set('pricing_value', 0);
}
```

Refresh your cache and check.

**EDIT**

To achieve what you require, there is a weird solution.
Undo the changes stated in above code. Now when you add the price for a product attribute in product section use `0.00` as value instead of `0` where you want to add **0** price and leave blank where you want to leave blank.

It seems weird but works with minimal effort and without core changes.

Comment: Thanks your answer, but it makes blank input to 0 too. What I want is when I set input 0, it is 0. When I leave it blank, it still blank. How to achieve that?

Comment: @ArthurSereno, please check my edit. Its working without any change to any file.

Comment: Thanks very much, the second way is a weird solution but work. I will choose a appropriate one form the two ways, base on needs.

Answer (score 2):

`'{{pricing_value}}'` is a **templating variables**, Magento has parser to recognize the codes and transform them into actions. You can assign variables to Magento, then using the double curly brackets syntax to retieve them, it often appears in email templates, invoices templates, etc. Some detail example you could see below:

[Magento - how to add custom variables to new order E-mail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358971/magento-how-to-add-custom-variables-to-new-order-e-mail)

[Advanced Transactional Email Templates](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2011/11/25/magento-advanced-transactional-email-templates/)

---

The processing of `'{{pricing_value}}'` is in `/js/mage/adminhtml/product.js`:

```
var pricingValue = parseFloat(templateVariables.get('pricing_value'));
if (!isNaN(pricingValue)) {
    templateVariables.set('pricing_value', pricingValue);
} else {
    templateVariables.unset('pricing_value');
}
```

When pricing_value is 0, Magento doesn't save it to table `catalog_product_super_attribute_pricing`, so pricingValue(0) is always get null, that is to say, pricingValue(0) is always NaN and like blank. So if you want

> when I set input 0, it is 0. When I leave it blank, it still blank

You should not set input 0, but set input `0.0` according to the answer of Jaimin, then `0.0000` will be saved to the table and work as you want.